# "How To Ask" tips are gone

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions, google-chrome, tips

When you go to Ask Question,, if you click in the body then you get How To Format on the right. If you click on the tags you get How To Tag on the right. I just now clicked in the title and I got a header How To Ask with no text under it. I am using Google Chrome stable channel.

Edit: How To Edit works in edit view

Comment: I see this on all sites using IE8 on XP. Truly a curious bug. [Here is an example screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/w3QRr.png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are currently under a build freeze but this will go out with the next one - hopefully tonight.

Comment: Was it a programmer's goof? or is there a strange and interesting cause?